# Generate a date range in Snowflake within a tabular UDF

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, generator

I'm trying to replace a PostGres function that generates a list of timestamps using the current timestamp that starts [X] [start datepart]s ago and ends with the current timestamp with an interval of [end datepart]s.  For example, a user could ask for a series that starts five days ago and returns a timestamp for every hour.

I've found plenty of examples that do something like this using the GENERATOR function. This is how it is done now:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_get_timestamps_in_range(grain VARCHAR, start_tsmp TIMESTAMP_TZ, maxrange NUMERIC(38,0)) 
RETURNS TABLE(out_tsmp TIMESTAMP_TZ)
LANGUAGE SQL 
STRICT 
AS 
$$
SELECT CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC', CASE LOWER(grain) 
                                    WHEN 'min'   THEN DATEADD('min',  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NULL) - 1, start_tsmp)
                                    WHEN 'hour'  THEN DATEADD('hour', ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NULL) - 1, start_tsmp)
                                    WHEN 'day'   THEN DATEADD('day',  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NULL) - 1, start_tsmp)
                                    WHEN 'month' THEN DATEADD('month',ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NULL) - 1, start_tsmp)
                                    WHEN 'year'  THEN DATEADD('year', ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NULL) - 1, start_tsmp)
                               END) FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT=>maxrange)) ORDER BY 1
$$
;
```

However, to use that function I have to provide maxrange -- i.e. know how many rows are going to be returned -- so I have to do a DATEDIFF([datepart], start, end).  I have this in a function:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_get_datediff(grain VARCHAR, start_tsmp TIMESTAMP_TZ, end_tsmp TIMESTAMP_TZ) 

RETURNS NUMBER(18,0)
LANGUAGE SQL 
STRICT 
AS 
$$
CASE LOWER(grain) 
     WHEN 'min'   THEN DATEDIFF('min',  start_tsmp, end_tsmp)
     WHEN 'hour'  THEN DATEDIFF('hour', start_tsmp, end_tsmp)
     WHEN 'day'   THEN DATEDIFF('day',  start_tsmp, end_tsmp)
     WHEN 'month' THEN DATEDIFF('month',start_tsmp, end_tsmp)
     WHEN 'year'  THEN DATEDIFF('year', start_tsmp, end_tsmp)
     ELSE -1
END + 1::NUMERIC(18,0)
$$
;
```

Try as I may, the GENERATOR will not accept that result -- I keep getting "argument 1 to function GENERATOR needs to be constant" error.  Even if the calc is performed in a calling UDF, the error still returns.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(fn_get_timestamps_in_range(
                        $end_grain  
                       ,fn_get_offset_start_tsmp($start_grain, 1 - $start_range, $time_zone)
                       ,fn_get_datediff($end_grain
                                           ,etl.fn_get_offset_start_tsmp($start_grain, 1 - $start_range, $time_zone)
                                           ,etl.fn_normalize_date($end_grain, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, $time_zone))
                    )
)
;
```

...returns the error:

```
SQL compilation error: argument 1 to function GENERATOR needs to be constant, found '(CAST(DATE_DIFFTIMESTAMPINMINUTES(DATE_ADDMINUTESTOTIMESTAMP(-19, ENSURE_NULLABLE('2022-01-05 21:01:00.000000000Ztz=1080')), ENSURE_NULLABLE('2022-01-05 21:01:00.000000000Ztz=1080')) AS NUMBER(18,0))) + 1'
```

If I replace the datediff call with a number, it works fine.

How can I get the GENERATOR function to accept the values I need?

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution -- I set a static value for the GENERATOR and then put a QUALIFY statement on it to limit the values to the first maxrange returned.  Sorry if I wasted anyone's time.

The resulting code looked like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_get_timestamps_in_range(grain VARCHAR, start_tsmp TIMESTAMP_TZ, end_tsmp TIMESTAMP_TZ) 
RETURNS TABLE(out_tsmp TIMESTAMP_TZ)
LANGUAGE SQL 
STRICT 
AS 
$$
SELECT CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC', CASE LOWER(grain) 
                                    WHEN 'min'   THEN DATEADD('min',  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NULL) - 1, start_tsmp)
                                    WHEN 'hour'  THEN DATEADD('hour', ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NULL) - 1, start_tsmp)
                                    WHEN 'day'   THEN DATEADD('day',  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NULL) - 1, start_tsmp)
                                    WHEN 'month' THEN DATEADD('month',ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NULL) - 1, start_tsmp)
                                    WHEN 'year'  THEN DATEADD('year', ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NULL) - 1, start_tsmp)
                               END) AS tsmp 
                               FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT=>10000)) 
                               QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NULL) < fn_get_datediff(grain, start_tsmp, end_tsmp) + 1
                               ORDER BY 1
$$
;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: To @Community's point, could you include a query that demonstrates these changes in action? Also, no need to apologize. It's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question if you feel it will help future readers with similar problems.

Comment: Sorry, was in a rush, I've added the end result to the original answer.